# Alterar link de botão de acordo com um option

Tags: javascript, html

Galera boa tarde.

Como faço uma função em javascript para obter o valor do input e de acordo com o input redirecionar para o link que eu quero.

```
Turma 1 - Option 1
Turma 2 - Option 2

Link turma1 ex: google.com.br
Link turma2 ex: yahoo.com.br
```

Quero que meu botão pegueo link de acordo com o option de escolha.

Como faço ?

```html
<div class="escolha-turma">
  <input type="radio" class="radiu" id="turma1" value="google.com.br">
  <div class="col-md-5 box">
    <strong>Inicio</strong>
    <span>08/05/2018</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 box">
    <strong>Termino</strong>
    <span>08/05/2018</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="escolha-turma">
  <input type="radio" class="radiu" id="turma2" value="yahoo.com.br">
  <div class="col-md-5 box">
    <strong>Inicio</strong>
    <span>08/05/2018</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 box">
    <strong>Termino</strong>
    <span>08/05/2018</span>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#">Pega o link do input radio escolhido</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar `addEventListener` para os `radios`.

> Mas é preciso colocar um `name` igual para cada `input radio`, como
>   fiz no exemplo abaixo. Coloque também uma classe no `<a>` para que o código não pegue outro tag `<a>` da página.

```js
let radios = document.body.querySelectorAll(".radiu");
for(let x=0; x<radios.length; x++){
   radios[x].addEventListener("click", e => {
      document.querySelector(".link_a").href = "http://"+e.target.value;
   });
}
```

```html
<div class="escolha-turma">
  <input name="radiu" type="radio" class="radiu" id="turma1" value="google.com.br">
  <div class="col-md-5 box">
    <strong>Inicio</strong>
    <span>08/05/2018</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 box">
    <strong>Termino</strong>
    <span>08/05/2018</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="escolha-turma">
  <input name="radiu" type="radio" class="radiu" id="turma2" value="yahoo.com.br">
  <div class="col-md-5 box">
    <strong>Inicio</strong>
    <span>08/05/2018</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 box">
    <strong>Termino</strong>
    <span>08/05/2018</span>
  </div>
</div>

<a class="link_a" href="#">Pega o link do input radio escolhido</a>
```

Comment: Eu testei aqui no site funcionou, porém joguei no meu arquivo no servidor e não funcionou, tem que chamar alguma biblioteca? obrigado

Comment: Não precisa de biblioteca, é JavaScript puro.

Comment: Vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: Coloquei uma classe no <a>, talvez seja esse o erro. Dá uma olhada na atualização da resposta.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null. Quando chama a classe '.radiu', apresentou esse erro no console

Comment: Tem que colocar o código após o HTML.

Comment: Agora foi, muito obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 1):

Seria essa a sua dúvida?

Inseri dois exemplos em javascript e utilizando a biblioteca jQuery.

```js
function FunJavaScript()
{
  var selectValue = document.getElementById("select").value;
  document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = selectValue;
  document.getElementById("link").href = selectValue;
}

function FunJquery()
{
  var selectValue = $("#select").val();
  $("#link").html(selectValue);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="http://www.google.com.br">Turma 1</option>
  <option value="http://www.yahoo.com.br">Turma 2</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Javascript" onclick="FunJavaScript()"></input>
<input type="button" value="jQuery" onclick="FunJquery()"></input><br/>
<a id="link" target="_blank"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ai está uma solução, utilizei o value do select para armazenar o link, mas você pode usar outras estratégias, mapear um valor e identificar o link etc..

```js
var select = document.querySelector('#linkOpt')
var link = document.querySelector('#link');

select.addEventListener('change', () => {
  let selected = select.item(select.selectedIndex);
  
  if(selected.value == '') {
    link.href = '#';
    link.innerHTML = '';
  } else {
    link.href = selected.value;
    link.innerHTML = selected.innerHTML;
  }
  
});
```

```html
<select id='linkOpt'>
  <option value="">-- Selecione --</option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
  <option value="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</option>
</select>

<a id='link' target="_blank" href='#'></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function trocarPagina(){
   var f = document.forms['seguir'].turma || document.forms.seguir.turma
   var o = f.selectedIndex;
   console.log(o);
   if(o == "1"){
   window.location.href = window.location.href+"/turma1.html";
   }
   
   if(o == "2"){
   window.location.href = window.location.href+"/turma2.html";
   }
   
   if(o == "3"){
   window.location.href = window.location.href+"/turma3.html";
   }
   
}
```

```html
<form name="seguir">
<select name="turma">
<option>Selecione...</option>
<option>Turma 1</option>
<option>Turma 2</option>
<option>Turma 3</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="ACESSAR" onclick="trocarPagina()" />
</form>
```